# Converting HTML/PHP system to ASP.net

Tags: php, html, windows, asp-classic

I am currently building a document template system in PHP/HTML and mySQL. However it only works in browser. I wanted to make it into a standalone software, for Windows. How can I make that transition to ASP? I am going to use MS Visual Studio 2010.

Is it possible to make the system into the that windowed box style? and of course I need to use database to store and call the data back. I just need a guideline on what to use and where to start.

Here is a piece of example of the document template.
[image: document template]

Comment: This is more of a HTML question. What back-end software you use is not really relevant. This can be done using a `<table>` element and the `border` CSS properties

Comment: You sound extremely confused.

Comment: If I got this right, I think he wants to create a windows application which creates invoices so there wouldn't be a need to have internet connection to create them.

Comment: Yes I was confused. The reply below cleared everything for me. :D Thank you for the reply guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic answer to your question is that to do what you want to do, you're going to need to throw away every single line of code you already have, and start the whole thing over again from scratch.

VB.Net is a completely different product to PHP, and moving from a browser-based system to a desktop application is an even bigger leap.

No-one here is going to give you an answer that will really help you make the switch you're asking, because it's too much to answer.

A few small thoughts for you though:

1. You can install PHP/Apache/MySQL on your local desktop machine. If the problem is that you want to use the software without being on the internet, then you can run it locally on your machine. Even while it's still in the browser.
2. PHP can be used to write desktop applications. There is a library called [PHP GTK](http://gtk.php.net/) which allows you to do this. It will involve a *lot* of changes to your system, but it will still be PHP, so it might be helpful for you.
3. If it's just the browser itself that's the problem, you could write a small desktop program in Visual Studio that loads the existing HTML system into a webview control.
4. You asked about writing ASP code. ASP is also a web-based system, like PHP, so it isn't suitable for writing a desktop application. If you want to do that, you'll need to use VB.Net. You've also used the tag "asp-classic" in your question tags. This is a very old version of ASP, which isn't supported any more. If you do write ASP code, it will be ASP.Net. But you'll be better off writing in VB.Net if you want to write a desktop app.

Comment: I see. So I guess I am just a confused beginner I guess. Well I do intend to write my codes from scratch. So might as well try a new approach. I do installed XAMPP to work locally but it would be more handy having a desktop app. So I'll need to learn VB.net to make a desktop app? Can I use the visual studio 2010 to do it?

By the way, any good online site for learning from beginning for VB.net? If possible the one with examples on creating database and such.

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely have to start over, if you had started the project in a .NET language to start with would likely be doable and not that hard to convert into a standalone project. The database should be useable I'd think and that might actually be the most important part that matters honestly.